# K-Clique in Connected Graphs

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, clique

A question about the clique problem (specifically k-clique). Is there any algorithm that takes advantage of the properties of connected graphs to find cliques of a given size `k`, if such cliques exist?

Comment: do you mean graphs with disconnected subgraphs? (I don't know the exact terminology, apologies if that doesn't make sense).

Comment: you can't have a graph without connected components, unless the graph has no verts.

Comment: @didierc Yes, I think that's it. I'm not very familiar with the terminology either. I guess I'll just change the question to say "islands".

Comment: @tmyklebu It seems the term I was looking for is "connected graphs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any algorithm can be made to take advantage of connected components. Just find the connected components before running the algorithm, discard those smaller than `k` and run the algorithm separately on each of the remaining ones.

Comment: that's basically what I was thinking about.